# How do I make this Salesforce cURL request in PHP?

Tags: php, rest, curl, salesforce

I'm using PHP to make cURL requests to Salesforce's REST API.
I've got most of the requests I need to make figured out, but I'm not sure how to convert the following `curl` command on the following Salesforce API page to a cURL request in PHP:

```
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/customExtIdField__c/11999 -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @newrecord.json -X PATCH
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm

I know that that `-H` option is for headers, which I'm handing with the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

And I **think** that the `-X PATCH` part can be accomplished with the following PHP cURL option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
```

However, how do I handle the `-d @newrecord.json` part in PHP cURL?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing with `-d @newrecord.json` is uploading a (JSON) file for the endpoint to use. To replicate this in PHP, you need to pass an array with a `file` element to `CUROPT_POSTFIELDS`, like this:

```
$file = [
    "file" => "@newrecord.json";
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
```

Make sure to give the correct file path. You can use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to aid with this.

Alternatively, you could just send the JSON encoded data:

```
$data = [
    "site" => "Stack Overflow",
    "help" => true,
];
$jsonData = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
```

Don't forget to set your `Content-Type: application/json` header!

Lastly, your guess about the `PATCH` request is correct:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. Just out of curiosity, is there any way to send the JSON data without sending a file? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Thanks. jpalmer4444 also had the same answer, but I marked yours as the right answer because it was a bit more complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should POST the json

`$post = json_encode($data);`

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);`

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` seems to take data in the following format for the `$post` variable: `$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');` As such, is the JSON data the actual string data? What does the parameter name need to be? Thanks.

Comment: The JSON data is the actual string data. So you don't need to name it anything though I believe cURL will wrap it as the {body : JSON}, but again - you shouldn't have to worry about that, simple pass the JSON data that lives in the file @newrecord.json.